# Should you dispose items in the FormClosing event?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

The following code seems to work fine:

```
Private Sub frmCalendar_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
  If qCal IsNot Nothing Then qCal.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Visual Studio Code Analysis generates a warning:
`"CA2213    Disposable fields should be disposed    'frmCalendar' contains field 'frmCalendar.qCal' that is of IDisposable type: 'clsCalendar'. Change the Dispose method on 'frmCalendar' to call Dispose or Close on this field."`

Is there a good reason not to leave the Dispose calls in the FormClosing event?

Comment: Most programmers feel uncomfortable about moving the Dispose() method from the Form.Designer.cs file to the Form.cs file.  Fear installed by the "don't edit the designer file!" caution.  This is unwarranted.  Cut/paste it to solve your problem.

Comment: That describes me precisely -- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would dispose of your objects in your form's Dispose() method. That ensures that your resources will only get disposed once there are no more references to your form anymore. You never know when in the future someone will want to resurrect your closed form, and now you've disposed of resources that the form may need. In your case it may not matter, but in a general sense, always put your disposing code in your Dispose() method

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you make a form Visual Studio generates the Dispose functions for you so you don't need to, for example in C# you get:

```
partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Text = "Form1";
        }

        #endregion
    }
```